# Which Heroku config vars are managed by addons?

Tags: heroku, environment-variables, heroku-cli

Is there a way to list/see which of the Heroku config vars in a Heroku app are added and managed by addons?

I don't see this distinction in the Heroku Dashboard.
I also don't see a distinction when I do `heroku config` from the command line.